# How to install Airflow in systemd files in ubuntu 16

Tags: systemd

I am not very good with linux and its terms.

I have install airflow. 
Airflow scheduler and webserver work using airflow scheduler & airflow webserver -p 8080.

I want to used systemd file, so it can run in background, and if it fails it restart.

I am following instruction.

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/scripts/systemd

I have saved following service files to /etc/systemd/system

1. airflow-webserver.service
2. airflow-scheduler.service

airflow-scheduler.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow scheduler daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=ubuntu
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/airflow scheduler -n ${SCHEDULER_RUNS}
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

airflow-scheduler.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Airflow webserver daemon
After=network.target postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=postgresql.service mysql.service redis.service rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/airflow
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/airflow webserver --pid /run/airflow/webserver.pid
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Few question

1. Do we need to make sure service postgresql.service, mysql.service, redis.service, rabbitmq-server.service
2. ExecStart runs specific command, what is  bin/airflow webserver --pid /run/airflow/webserver.pid doing, how to do same thing in ubuntu
3. Where we are running  airflow scheduler & airflow webserver -p 8080

Any tips ??

Thanks

Comment: You mention both Arch Linux and Ubuntu Linux. Which one are you using? Which version?

Comment: Just Ubuntu 16, updated question

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? The Airflow instructions are for Redhat/Centos, and there are some minor changes for Debian / Ubuntu systems. The EnvironmentFile should be placed in /etc/default/airflow and that corresponding line updated in both these systemd unit files. Note that both of these files should be chmod to 664 (as per systemd standard) and there are other files you need to deal with too, the `airflow` file, `airflow.conf` and you will need to create an airflow user too. I can see you have user:ubuntu group:airflow in one unit file above inconsistent with the other unit file.

Answer (score 1):

> Do we need to make sure service postgresql.service, mysql.service, redis.service, rabbitmq-server.service

If Airflow depends on any combination of these services being running, then you should make sure you've installed the appropriate packages and set them to run.

As far as I'm aware, the `After=` and `Wants=` directives don't require that the services actually succeed in starting up, so you don't necessarily need to have both PostgreSQL and MySQL be installed if Airflow doesn't require both them to be running.

> ExecStart runs specific command, what is `bin/airflow webserver --pid /run/airflow/webserver.pid` doing, how to do same thing in ubuntu

That's starting the Airflow web server and storing the process ID (PID) of the process at `/run/airflow/webserver.pid`. That will work in Ubuntu, assuming Airflow is installed at `/bin/airflow`

> Where we are running airflow scheduler & airflow webserver -p 8080

The scheduler is started in `scheduler.service` with

```
 ExecStart=/bin/airflow scheduler -n ${SCHEDULER_RUNS}
```

There is no reference to `-p 8080` because [running on port 8080 is the default behavior](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/start.html).

> Any tips ??

If you aren't sure about a particular `systemd` directive, you can look up where it is documented by finding it in `man systemd.directives`

For a general introduction to `systemd`, I recommend the series "Systemd for system administrators"

- http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-for-admins-1.html
- http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-for-admins-2.html
- http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-for-admins-3.html